# Will updating my MacBook Pro to OSX Yosemite delete/ruin my current files on desktop

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I'm currently working on an Xcode project that I have on my desktop. I'm currently using OSX version 10.9.5. If I update my mac to OSX Yosemite 10.10.3, will this delete all my projects/files with Xcode 6.1 that I have on desktop that i'm working on?

Answer (score 3):

It probably won't, but just to be safe, it never hurts to take a backup! Take a Time Machine backup of your hard drive, and then upgrade. Worst-case scenario, you lose your Xcode files, in which case you can just wipe your hard drive and restore from the backup.

Comment: +1 for the backup recommendation. As a rule, if you have files you don't want to lose, you should have a backup. This is true when upgrading because sometimes things go wrong during upgrades, but it's true at all other times as well, because upgrades aren't the only time things can go wrong.